# Can't change RelativeLayout background onTouch

Tags: android, background, runtime, android-relativelayout

I've got a strange issue. I have a class that inherits from `RelativeLayout`. I inflate to an xml. The default background image of this layout is set in the xml and I try to change it at run time when it's touched:

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    System.out.println("Action down");
    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.event_cell_selected);
}
else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
    System.out.println("Action down");
    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.event_cell);
}
```

The resources `event_cell` and `event_cell_selected` are both .png files. Also, I see my logs. I really can't say what's going on here.

[edit]
Thanks guys for your quick answers. No error in logcat, here is the xml I inflate:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/event_cell"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
android:paddingLeft="14dp"
android:paddingRight="14dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_large" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMonth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="juil."
    android:textColor="@color/event_header"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textViewMonth"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/event_header"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/event_header"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewSeparator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textViewDay"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:src="@drawable/event_title_descr_separator" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageViewSeparator"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
```

And here is my root xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/navigationBarView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventsLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_small" >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The inflated RelativeLayout is added to the scrollView's linearlayout

[edit]
Ok to solve this problem I finally end-up setting my default background image programmatically (not through the xml). That does the trick. Android can really have weird behavior sometimes ...

Comment: Is there any errors?? post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show you layout xml and inflate code. I bet the problem is folowing: in you xml you are using RelativeLayout as a root. This means that then inflating you are adding relative layout defined in xml to the relative layout created in code (defined by you own class inherited from RelativeLayout). This means that background defined in xml is shown above backround you changing in code. Try using `<merge>` in you layout root instead of `<RelativeLayout>`

You can read about "merge" layout tag here 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/event_cell"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingRight="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_large" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMonth"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

   .............

</merge>
```

Comment: Can you show code where you are inflating this xml? Something like inflate(context, R.layout.my_layout, this)?

Comment: String service = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
  LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(service);
  li.inflate(R.layout.other_event_cell, this);

Comment: This is inside constructor of you RalativeLayout inherited class? Correct?

Comment: Then use "merge" instead of "RelativeLayout" in first xml you posted and it should be ok. Just set paddings, background and other attributes of you Relative layout from code.

Comment: Thanks but is there another way ? I really need a relative layout here. I use properties such as 'below' a lot here.

Comment: You still will be with relative layout. Updated my answer

Comment: But I don't think this will solve the problem. My xml is like this after my code ran: RelativeLayout->ScrollView->LinearLayout->RelativeLayout(inflated)*, the * means that it's a list.

Comment: Did you checked layout with hierarchy viewer tool?

Comment: don't need it, each relative layout I inflate is a cell in my linearlayout and is displayed perfectly in my linear layout. Plus I instantiate my RelativeLayout subclass and add it to the linearlayout.

Comment: Just try "merge" and tell me what you see. I'm sure like a hell that this is an issue and this will fix it.

Comment: Ok tried merge (just replaced RelativeLayout by merge). It almost solved my problem: No image are set at the beginning but then the excepted behavior is reached. My padding are gone though. Thanks for your help but I still don't understand why it almost solve my issue

Comment: Read blog post I linked in my answer. You will find all details there. And now I want my accept to reach a mighty 2k mark!

Comment: Ok I'll give you your accept cause you put effort trying to help me out. But TBH, I won't use this solution and find another one. Cheers anyway

Comment: Ok though I think this is the best solution I can tell you another one. Remove android:background="@drawable/event_cell" in you xml and add setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.event_cell); just after li.inflate(R.layout.other_event_cell, this); This way you will have perfectly right layout and exactly that behaviour you need. The only problem you can have here if you background is 9-patch drawable. This solution is worse than the first one because in this case you have two nested relative layouts and one of this layout is useless.

Comment: Also to understand what happening you can add layout_margin="20dip" to RelativeLayout xml. This way you will see that RelativeLayout inflated from xml is added just above you custom layout inherited from RelativeLayout. Another way is to set background in xml to some translucent color. Also you can inherit you custom layout from FrameLayout for example and see that everything is working as before.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that i see, is the `System.out.println("Action down");` is duplicated in both of your conditions. This could cause issues when trying to look for problems in your log.

---

Also, you say:

> I try to change it at run time when it's touched...

If you are wanting to just change it when it is touched, try using an `OnClickListener` instead of the `Touch` stuff you are using.

---

Also, your second condition is an `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`, is that supposed to be `ACTION_UP`?

Comment: OnCLick happens when the touch is released, I want it to happen when it starts. And yes my log are bad but it's not the issue